# How to debug "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value X to data type int"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '10/2/2017' to data type int

I don't know how to overcome this? Here is the code I am using. I know something is wrong with when statement but don't know how to convert that?

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Customers.EmailAddress,
    COUNT(Orders.OrderID) as NumOrders,
    CASE 
       WHEN Customers.Custom_Field_Custom2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 499999 
          THEN '$1000-$499,999'
    END AS REV
FROM 
    Customers, Orders
WHERE  
    Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
    AND Orders.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Payment Declined')
    AND Orders.OrderDate BETWEEN '05/01/2016 00:00' AND '4/30/2017 23:59'
GROUP BY 
    Customers.EmailAddress, Customers.Custom_Field_Custom2
```

Comment: What are you honestly expecting `10/2/2017` represented as an `INT` to look like...?

Comment: Take a look at your `Customers.Custom_Field_Custom2` column data - you might be getting this error because of the data in that field.

Comment: Side note, you don't need `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY` it's redundant.

Comment: i am having date fields in results.i want code to exclude these date fields and wherever there is numeric value assign taht bucket to it. Is that make sense?

Comment: @Aaron Dietz Thankyou for letting me know. I will remove that.

Comment: @c_174 Not really.. please show some sample data to illustrate what you're trying to explain.

Comment: yes siyual i have lot of date fields in that data Customers.Custom_Field_Custom2. But i have numeric values too on which i am trying to applying buckets. so what is is the solution for this? If anyone can help me with this

Comment: @ Siyual custom_field_custom2
2701000
5/28/2016
1000
45259
5/7/2016
MED-HIGH
5/26/2016

here is sample data in  Customers.Custom_Field_Custom2. I am trying to assign buckets only to numeric values like 1000,2701000 where conversion is failing

Comment: custom_field_custom2
2701000
5/28/2016
1000
45259
5/7/2016
MED-HIGH
5/26/2016

Comment: @c_174 What dbms are you using?  ie. SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle

Comment: @ Aaron Dietz ms sql 2008

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Generally you will want to say `Orders.OrderDate >= '05/01/2016 00:00' AND Orders.OrderDate < '5/1/2017 00:00'` because fractional seconds suck.  BETWEEN is just syntactic sugar so you're not losing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's get rid of the `DISTINCT` since `GROUP BY` handles that, then change your join to be explicit and add aliases.  The implicit syntax is depreciated and the aliases simplify things:

```
SELECT C.EmailAddress,
       COUNT(O.OrderID) as NumOrders,
       CASE WHEN C.Custom_Field_Custom2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 499999  
            THEN '$1000-$499,999'
       END AS REV
FROM Customers C
JOIN Orders O on O.CustomerId = C.CustomerID
WHERE O.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled','Payment Declined')
AND O.OrderDate BETWEEN '05/01/2016 00:00' AND '4/30/2017 23:59'
GROUP BY C.EmailAddress, C.Custom_Field_Custom2
```

Then to only look at numeric data in `C.Custom_Field_Custom2`, use `ISNUMERIC(C.Custom_Field_Custom2) = 1`:

```
SELECT C.EmailAddress,
       COUNT(O.OrderID) as NumOrders,
       CASE WHEN C.Custom_Field_Custom2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 499999  
            THEN '$1000-$499,999'
       END AS REV
FROM Customers C
JOIN Orders O on O.CustomerId = C.CustomerID
WHERE ISNUMERIC(C.Custom_Field_Custom2) = 1
AND O.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled','Payment Declined')
AND O.OrderDate BETWEEN '05/01/2016 00:00' AND '4/30/2017 23:59'
GROUP BY C.EmailAddress, C.Custom_Field_Custom2
```

You might also consider adding an `ELSE` to your `CASE` statement, if you want things outside of your 1000-499999 range to return as something other than `NULL`

Comment: thanku so much..it worked.. can u plz clear my one more doubt? Why we didnt use cast or convert in case?

Comment: @c_174 Sure thing.  We didn't use cast or convert because there is data in `Custom_Field_Custom2` that can't be converted to a number (from your example data: '5/7/2016' 'MED-HIGH' '5/26/2016' - can't convert slashes or letters to numbers).  You said in comments that you only wanted to the compare to happen on the numeric data anyway, so we made sure we only look at numeric data by adding the `ISNUMERIC()` to the where clause.

Comment: got it..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for there to be a date in your `Customers.Custom_Field_Custom2` field?

**EDITED**
Just saw some of the comments below your question.

Since you have varying data types in that column, you will need to filter out the unwanted data before attempting to compare it. Below, I've moved the Customers table into a subquery so we can weed out anything with alphabetic characters or the '/' which all dates have. If there is anything else funky you need to filter for, add it to the subquery.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    C.EmailAddress,
    COUNT(O.OrderID) as NumOrders,
    CASE 
       WHEN C.Custom_Field_Custom2 BETWEEN 1000 AND 499999 
          THEN '$1000-$499,999'
    END AS REV
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Custom_Field_Custom2 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
    AND CHARINDEX('/', Custom_Field_Custom2) = 0
    ) C INNER JOIN Orders O ON O.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
WHERE  
    C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID 
    AND O.OrderStatus NOT IN ('Cancelled', 'Payment Declined')
    AND O.OrderDate BETWEEN '05/01/2016 00:00' AND '4/30/2017 23:59'
GROUP BY 
    C.EmailAddress, C.Custom_Field_Custom2
```